# Uploadify conflict with jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, uploadify

I have trying to create file upload using jQuery-UI dialog and uploadify. I have seen that others also had similar problem, but it was always z-index in css or cross-browser issue, which is not case here because it just won't work in any browser. When I place uploadify div(div that is a placeholder for flash object) outside the jQuery dialog everything works fine, but when I try to put it inside, swf gets loaded but when dialog pops I get error: 'Object expected' in jquery.min.js on

`var c=a.getAttributeNode("tabindex")`

Is it possible that problem is caused by jquery version? Current version is 1.7.1 and I tried using also 1.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS class to override the default `z-index` value 1

```
.swfupload {
    z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I can now click on 'Browse' button and select file dialog appears, but I still get same error in the IE. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, it is a SWFUpload problem : http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/issues/detail?id=371&can=1&q=IE9&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20FixReleasedIn%20FixTargetedFor%20Modified

Comment: You need to downloadlast version of swfupload, replace it in the uplodify source, then fix the problem I mentionned above. Painful, I know...

Comment: Here is a good workaround : http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/9155/uploadify-version-3-2-does-not-work-in-ie9/p1

Answer (score 0):

this error in absence function getAttributeNode and getAttribute in Flash element.
change in "jquery-min.js"

```
elem.getAttributeNode(name) // OR a.getAttributeNode(b)
```

to

```
(elem.getAttributeNode?elem.getAttributeNode(name):null) // OR (a.getAttributeNode?a.getAttributeNode(b):null)
```

and

```
elem.getAttribute(name) // OR a.getAttribute(b)
```

to

```
(elem.getAttribute?elem.getAttribute(name):null) // OR (a.getAttribute?a.getAttribute(b):null)
```